# Watchdog did not stop?

Tags: raspberry-pi

When I reboot my Raspberry Pi (running NOOBS and its a rpi 3) in the root/command line thing, it prints something like this:

```
[ (numbers) ] Watchdog: watchdog did not stop!
```

Is this something to worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior. If the Raspberry Pi reboots sucessfully, there is nothing to worry about.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249654

> The watchdog did not stop! line is normal behavior. systemd sets a "hardware watchdog" timer as a failsafe, to ensure that if the normal shutdown process freezes/fails that the computer will still shutdown after the specified period of time.